# Unknown Identifier while using function?

Tags: haxe, haxeflixel

In player.hx:

```
public function new(X, Y, _upKey:String, _downKey:String){
    super(X, Y);

makeGraphic(20, 20, FlxColor.RED);

immovable = true;
}
```

In PlayState.hx:

```
override public function create():Void
{
    super.create();

    add(new Enemy(300, FlxG.height - 20, 10, 20));
    add(new Enemy(500, FlxG.height - 40, 10, 40));

    add(player = new Player(60, FlxG.height - 40, "UP", "DOWN"));
}
```

It returns to me with the errors "Unknown identifier: upKey" and "Unknown identifier: downKey" in the Player.hx file, even after I already set those in the function. How do I fix this?

Comment: At what line does the error point? What does the code there look like?

Comment: source/Player.hx:31: characters 28 - 33: Unknown Identifier: upKey
------
Line 31 in actual code:

if (FlxG.keys.anyPressed([upKey])){

Comment: Are you sure `Player` has a variable called `upKey`? Please show us a more complete version of `Player.hx`.

Comment: Player's upKey variable is supposed to be defined as a function argument... Or am I doing this wrong? http://i.imgur.com/o9IztU0.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function arguments are only available in that particular function (this is known as the *scope* of the variable) - so just because your constructor has arguments named `upKey` and `downKey`, that doesn't mean you can also automatically use them in another function like `update()`.

To be able to do that, you need to save the arguments to member variables of the `Player` class:

```
class Player extends FlxSprite
{
    var upKey:String;
    var downKey:String;

    public function new(X, Y, upKey:String, downKey:String)
    {
        super(X, Y);
        this.upKey = upKey;
        this.downKey = downKey;
    }

    override public function update():Void
    {
        super.update();
        trace(upKey, downKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I understand now! Thanks!